# Use slot-scoped data in the component script in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vue, I have a component A with a slot that returns an object as the slot-scoped in the component B using it:

*component A template:*

```
<template>
<div>
   <slot :myObject="myObject" />
</div>
</template>
```

*component B template:*

```
<template>
<component-a>
  <template slot-scope="{myObject}">
    <!-- uses myObject -->
  </template>
</component-a>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports={
     data(){
       return {
          myObject: null // This never updates with the new value
       }
     }
  }
 </script>
```

Everything works fine in the html template of component B, however, I cannot access to `myObject` in the script of component B. I could create a child component (C) that accepts myObject as a prop and have all the needed logic there, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an appropriate use of slot scope. A simple prop would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use slot-scope you are basically passing data to the slot, from the component, which is hosting the slot (not the with the content of the slot). 
In your case if you want to use data slot-scope, you have to pass the data from component A. So the data-source myObject must exist in component A.

So the right approach would look something like this:

**Component A**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot :myObject="myObject" />
        <button @click="changeMyObject">Change MyObject</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "slot-scope-component",
        data(){
            return {
                myObject: {
                    value: "ABC"
                }
            }
        },
        methods:{
            changeMyObject() {
                this.myObject = {
                    value: "XYZ"
                };
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Component B**

```
<template>
    <ComponentA>
        <template slot-scope="props">
            {{props.myObject}}
        </template>
    </ComponentA>
</template>

<script>
    import ComponentA from '@/components/ComponentA';

    export default {
        components: {
            ComponentA
        },
    }
</script>
```

As well there was a little spelling mistake: You wrote *slot-scoped* instead of *slot-scope*

You can improve that code further by using destructuring:

```
slot-scope="{myObject}"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your example, but using the data in component A script is not a problem, my question is if it is possible to use it in component B

Comment: Oh that's what you ment: You have to know that the data-object myObject only exists in the Slot and not in componentB itself (It is passed from component A into the slot and it's scope is only the slot, that's why it is called slot-scope).

If you want to use myObject in componentB then you can pass it into some event like  this: 
      
@click="changeMyObject(myObject)"